# Swift UITableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt image is all white

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've implemented the following method below and while the functionality works the image displayed is completely white in color. Is there a property within the editing style that I need to change?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { _, _, completion in
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.viewModel.remove(atIndex: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
        completion(true)
    }
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(named:"trash-can") // Image is red in Assets but here it's completely white
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Navy") ?? .blue
    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    return configuration
}
```

[image: Image has white overlay]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to find the answer and it's down to two things. First, the view hierarchy showed a white tint applied to the image after the fact, which couldn't be manipulated. Second, in order to solve the issue, the image needed to be created using CGImage and wrapping it in an overriding rendering mode class.

Here's the working code. Also when implementing, pay attention to the scale factor - In my case, I needed the image to be half the width of the view and needed a scale of 1.5, not 0.5 as you would naturally add :)

UIImage wrapper class:

```
class OriginalImageRender: UIImage {
    override func withRenderingMode(_ renderingMode: UIImage.RenderingMode) -> UIImage {
    return self
 }
}
```

Implementation:

```
    let cgImageX =  UIImage(named: "trash-can")?.cgImage
    deleteAction.image = OriginalImageRender(cgImage: cgImageX!, scale: 1.5, orientation: .up)
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Navy") ?? .blue
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIImage(named: "trash-can").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: This does not work

Comment: @user7684436 in the `Attributes inspector` is the `Render As` property set to `Original Image`?

Comment: Yes, I tried all options :). The image is there in the library as it's also used on another screen.

Comment: I'm guessing the image is displayed correctly on the other screen?

Comment: Yes & I've exported it twice and also tried other image formats (png, svg). It's code-based for sure as it's also the same for whatever image I replace it with.

Comment: Interesting... have you tried taking a look at the `Debug View Hierarchy`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239445/discussion-between-dispatchswift-and-user7684436).